# Got an error message for "Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to compute the sum for same IDs in each column in the data table. In the datatable there are empty elements. When I run the following code to the line calculating colP_sum, it gives me the error if "specific cast is not valid". It seems caused by the empty elements in the data table? How should I solve it? I am sure if the datatable is filled up with numbers this code works.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < LoadIDcount; i++)
        {
            string IDnow = LoadID[i, 0];
            string IDsaved = LoadP_dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();

            if (LoadP_dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() == IDnow)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8760; j++)
                {
                    string colPnow = SP_dt.Columns[j * 2 + 4].ColumnName.ToString();
                    double ColP_sum = (double)SP_dt.Compute(String.Format("Sum([{0}])", colPnow), String.Format("Load_ID = '{0}'", IDnow));
                    string colQnow = SP_dt.Columns[j * 2 + 5].ColumnName.ToString();
                    double ColQ_sum = (double)SP_dt.Compute(String.Format("Sum([{0}])", colQnow), String.Format("Load_ID = '{0}'", IDnow));


                    LoadP_dt.Rows[i][j + 2] = ColP_sum;
                    LoadQ_dt.Rows[i][j + 2] = ColQ_sum;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}    {1}", i, j);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID does not match");
            }

        }

        CSVfilewriter(CSVPpath, LoadP_dt);//save the Load_P datatable to CSV file
        CSVfilewriter(CSVQpath, LoadQ_dt);//save the Load_Q datatable to CSV file
        //CSVfilewriter(CSVSPpath, SP_dt);//save the service point datatable to CSV file



    }
```

Comment: @hat is the data type of the column you're trying to sum?  Just based on the name I'm _guessing_ it's a `DateTime`, and you can't sum `DateTime`s.

Comment: it is not datatime. The column name is date and time. I am trying to compute each column by column name.

Answer (score 0):

if "colPnow" is not a number, that could explain it: the "Compute" and "Sum" both appear to be expecting number value

Comment: No. colpnow is only to locate the column name. colpnow matches the column